# CSS: Scroll in fixed div-Container

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollbar, fixed

I'm trying to enable a working scroll bar on my page. The problem is that my div-container is fixed, because I have three relative divs that slice my background in three columns. I tried it with `overflow-y` but this has no effect on my div. It works just on the relative divs.

```css
body, html {
     height: 100%;
     min-height: 100%;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}
.bg_left {
     background-color: #333C33;
     background-position: left;
     background-repeat: repeat;
     float: left;
     position: relative;
}
.bg_middle {
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
     background-repeat: repeat;
     float: left;
     position: relative;
}
.bg_right {
     background-color: #005050;
     background-repeat: repeat;
     float: left;
     position: relative;
}
.top {
     position: fixed;
     text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="bg_left" style="width: 33.3%; height: 100%"></div>
      <div class="bg_middle" style="width: 33%; height: 100%"></div>
      <div class="bg_right" style="width: 33%; height: 100%"></div>
      <div class="top" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">Test
         <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
         <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
         test
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know how to enable the scroll bar or how to get rid of the relative background divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try a different approach, you want the background fixed in the left and the right, and the content inside.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<style type="text/css">
body, html {
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.bg_left {
background-color: #333C33;
background-position: left;
position: fixed;
left:0;
height: 100vh;
}
.bg_right {
background-color: #005050;
position: fixed;
right:0;
height: 100vh;
}
.top {
text-align:center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bg_left" style="width: 33.3%; height: 100%"></div>
<div class="bg_right" style="width: 33.3%; height: 100%"></div>
<div class="top" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">Test
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
test</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This will work, although it's still probably not the best solution. But it all depends in the real need you have. But try this out.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Simply Use overflow y:scroll. I have used height 200px. You can use accordingly. Use Code like :

```
.top {
    position: fixed;
    text-align:center;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

or check [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Rupalkataria/xem2podw/#&togetherjs=y6tvdFCMOl)

Answer (score 0):

You can enable scrolling inside an element by using `overflow: scroll;`

[Check this link for more information](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)